# Build paths of all paths of a tree structured array in php

Tags: php, tree, hierarchical-data

Hi I am trying to print categories and their children like a tree paths from db. Till now i am able to print the tree structured array like below.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => 'Furniture'
        [slug] => 'furniture'
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'Sofa'
                        [slug] => 'sofa'
                        [leafs] => Array
                            (
                               [0] => Array ( [name] => '3 Seater', [slug] = '3-seater'
                               [1] => Array ( [name] => '4 Seater', [slug] = '4-seater'
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'Chairs'
                        [slug] => 'chairs'
                        [leafs] => Array
                            (
                               [0] => Array ( [name] => '3 Seater', [slug] = '3-seater'
                               [1] => Array ( [name] => '4 Seater', [slug] = '4-seater'
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 'Furniture1'
        [slug] => 'furniture1'
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'Sofa1'
                        [slug] => 'sofa1'
                        [leafs] => Array
                            (
                               [0] => Array ( [name] => '3 Seater1', [slug] = '3-seater1'
                               [1] => Array ( [name] => '4 Seater1', [slug] = '4-seater1'
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'Chairs1'
                        [slug] => 'chairs1'
                        [leafs] => Array
                            (
                               [0] => Array ( [name] => '3 Seater1', [slug] = '3-seater1'
                               [1] => Array ( [name] => '4 Seater1', [slug] = '4-seater1'
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Some of the children may have leafs or some of the parents may have children. But what i am trying to print was like below.

```
Array(
[0] => 'Furniture/Sofa/3 Seater',
[1] => 'Furniture/Sofa/4 Seater',
[2] => 'Furniture/Chiars/ 3 Seater'
[3] => 'Furniture/Chiars/4 Seater',
[4] => 'Furniture1/Sofa1/3 Seater1',
[5] => 'Furniture1/Sofa/4 Seater1',
[6] => 'Furniture1/Chiars1/ 3 Seater1'
[7] => 'Furniture1/Chiars1/4 Seater1',
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: My aim is printing the paths but till now i am able to create the tree structured array only after this i am not able find solution. Any ideas also welcome.

Comment: Write a function, where you: Go through your array and add each values to your result array, but check if there is an inner array. If yes call the same function again just with the inner array and do this until you don't have any more inner arrays. Also make sure you pass your result array by reference to keep your values.

Comment: ^^ There you go, if you get stuck, post your attempt and where you don't get any further.

Comment: Hi ! This kind of question is pretty frequent and you might find something which looks like yours there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190772/how-to-create-an-html-dropdown-from-the-recursive-array-in-php/30190997#30190997

Answer (score 1):

It is a 'multi-way tree'.

**Update:** This is a complete redo of the code as a class `TreePaths`

[Original full source code at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/dwSub6UC) - [Execute at sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64eecae585a57cb4857c486f5367248eae32e3b0)

This answer describes the new code.

The changes:

- The input `array node` now only needs the `children` entry rather than 'leafs`. This makes the input more consistent.
- The only entry in the `array node` checked by this code is the `$node['children]`. This allows you have any other data in the node that you wish and you can process it in the `callable` in any way that you wish.
- The node processing can be replaced by any `callable` having the signature of:

  `function(array $currentPath, /* boolean */ $isTopALeaf)  {...`
- If the `nodeProcessor` (callable) returns a value that is not empty then it will be added to the `$allPaths` array.

#### External sources and demonstrations

- [The TreePaths class source code](http://pastebin.com/M6ABy81L)
- [The TreePaths Test Data](http://pastebin.com/CGPniY8C)

Website:

- [Website showing the 'default nodeProcessor' - run1.php](http://rfv123.eu5.net/treepaths/run1.php)
- [Website showing the 'HTML Anchor nodeProcessor' - run2.php](http://rfv123.eu5.net/treepaths/run2.php)

#### Description

The interesting part is that we have to store the 'path' to the 'leaf' nodes.
The 'path' seems to be 'special'. However, imagine every time you 'recurse' or 'nest' down one level then you record where you are on a 'stack'.
When you reach the end of the ' the current list you:

- Record the path via the 'stack' to the 'current leaf node'
- Call the `nodeProcessor`
- 'unnest' or 'pop' the top of the stack.

I use the 'tree structure' and names as provided.

At the end of every path, the `nodeProcessor` is called with `the current path`

Outputs:

- the 'full path' to any particular 'leaf' node.
- All the paths to every 'leaf' node.

As it is a tree then a 'recursive' algorithm is required as the 'depth' of the tree is unknown.

The program has to:

- traverse the 'tree'.
- maintain a 'stack' of node names as a 'path' to the current node
- run user code at selected nodes as required. I use a 'closure' for this in this code.
- store the output somewhere useful.

#### Node Processor (callable) - Replace the default one

```
/*
 * Generate an HTML anchor tag from the 'slug' entries
 */
$slugNodeProcessor =
    function(array $currentPath,
                     $isTopALeaf)  {

        /*
         * Lets make some HTML anchors for the Slugs?
         */
        $template = '<a href="%s" class="Slug">%s</a>';

        // top of the stack will be a leaf
        $title = '';
        $top  = end($currentPath); // easier to work with
        $prev = prev($currentPath); // need the description for title
        $title = $prev['name'] .' - '.  $top['name'];

        $url = '/';
        foreach($currentPath as $key => $node) {
                $url .= $node['Slug'] .'/';
        };
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $htmlSlug = sprintf($template, $url, $title);

        return $htmlSlug;
     };
```

#### The default 'nodeProcessor':

```
/**
     * If you don't provide a callable to generate paths then this will be used.
     *
     * It generates a string of names separated by '/'. i.e. it looks like a filepath.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function defaultNodeProcessor()
    {
        $dnp = function(array $currentPath,
                         $isTopALeaf)  {

                $fullPath = '/';
                foreach($currentPath as $key => $node) {
                    $fullPath .= $node['name'] .'/';
                }
                return rtrim($fullPath, '/');
             };
         return $dnp;
    }
```

#### Run the program:

```
$tree = new TreePaths($srcTree,
                      $slugNodeProcessor);
$tree->generate();
$allPaths = $tree->allPaths();
```

#### Output:

```
array (8) [
    string (67) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/3-seater" class="Slug">Sofa - 3 Seater</a>"
    string (67) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/4-seater" class="Slug">Sofa - 4 Seater</a>"
    string (76) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/chairs/3-seater" class="Slug">Chairs - 3 Seater</a>"
    string (76) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/chairs/4-seater" class="Slug">Chairs - 4 Seater</a>"
    string (94) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/chairs/furniture1/sofa1/3-seater1" class="Slug">Sofa1 - 3 Seater1</a>"
    string (94) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/chairs/furniture1/sofa1/4-seater1" class="Slug">Sofa1 - 4 Seater1</a>"
    string (104) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/chairs/furniture1/sofa1/chairs1/3-seater1" class="Slug">Chairs1 - 3 Seater1</a>"
    string (104) "<a href="/furniture/sofa/chairs/furniture1/sofa1/chairs1/4-seater1" class="Slug">Chairs1 - 4 Seater1</a>"
]
```

#### The class:

```
/*
 * Source Tree:
 *   
 * Tree Node:
 *
 * Array(
 *        "name" => 'Furniture',  // not checked
 *        "slug" => 'furniture',  // optional - not used
 *        "children" => Array( // will be other Tree nodes...
 *                          ),
 *      );
 *
 *  The `children` key is optional, if empty or missing, means it is a `leaf` node
 *
 *  !!! Note: The only array entry checked in here is 'children' !!!
 *
 *  But you will need to overide the default nodeProcessor.
 *
 *  The default `nodeProcessor` uses `name` and `children` only
 */

/*
 * NodeProcessor:
 *   o It is a callable that accepts two parameters
 *     o current path - an array of all the nodes so far in this path
 *     o isTopALeaf   - is the end of the path a 'leaf' node?
 */

/**
 *  Traverse the tree of `nodes`
 *  Generate a list of Paths from Root to every leaf node as an array of `nodes`.
 *  It is a `stack` with the top node being a leaf.
 */
class TreePaths {

    /**
     * The 'current' menu / tree
     *
     * @var array $tree
     */
    private $tree = array();


    /**
     * The Output
     *
     * @var array $allPaths
     */
    private $allPaths = array();

    /**
     * The 'current' stack of nodes in this path
     *
     * This is a 'stack'. The 'path' is all the entries combined.
     *
     * @var array $currentPath
     */
    private $currentPath = array();


    /**
     * The 'callable' to be run for nodes
     *
     * @var callable $nodeProcessor
     */
    private $nodeProcessor = null;


    /**
     * Call All Nodes or Leaf node only
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $callLeafNodesOnly = true;


    /**
     * Build the class but do not run it...
     *
     * Provides a default NodeProcessor if you don't provide one.
     *    o The default processor builds string paths that look like filepaths
     *
     * @param array $tree
     * @param callable $processNode        - optional
     * @param boolean $callLeafNodesOnly  - optional default true
     */
    public function __construct(array $tree,
                                   /* callable */ $processNode = null,
                                   $callLeafNodesOnly = true)
    {
        $this->tree = $tree;
        $this->nodeProcessor = $processNode;
        $this->callLeafNodesOnly = $callLeafNodesOnly;

        // provide a default processor
        if (is_null($this->nodeProcessor)) {
            $this->nodeProcessor = $this->defaultNodeProcessor();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This routine makes this class rather powerful as you can use any callable.
     *
     * @param type $nodeProcessor
     */
    public function setNodeProcessor(/* callable */ $nodeProcessor)
    {
        $this->nodeProcessor = $nodeProcessor;
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of all the paths that were generated by the 'nodeProcessor'
     * @return array
     */
    public function allPaths()
    {
        return $this->allPaths;
    }

    /**
     * The routine that processes one node and recurses as required
     *
     * @param array $node
     * @return void This is all side-effects
     */
    protected function treeWalk($node)
    {
        // always add the node to the currentPath
        array_push($this->currentPath, $node);

        // Always call the node processor and add the path to all paths if required
        $processedPath = $this->callNodeProcessor($this->currentPath,
                                                  $this->isLeafNode($node));
        if (!empty($processedPath)) { // add to all the paths
            $this->allPaths[] = $processedPath;
        }

        // do we recurse?
        if ($this->isLeafNode($node)) { // no we dont...
            array_pop($this->currentPath); // lose leaf node from top of stack
            return; // nothing more to do
        }

        // now process all the children... This will recurse - always
        foreach ($node['children'] as $key => $node) {
            $this->treeWalk($node);
        }
        return; // end of children
    }

    /**
     * Process all the top level nodes.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function generate()
    {
        $this->allPaths = array();

        foreach ($this->tree as $key => $node) {
            $this->treeWalk($node);
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * End of a path?
     *
     * @param array $node
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function isLeafNode($node)
    {
        return empty($node['children']);
    }

    /**
     * Are we in the 'middle' of a path?
     *
     * @param array $node
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function hasChildren($node)
    {
        return !empty($node['children']);
    }


    /**
     * The `callable` to be called.
     *
     * It must accept the two parameters.
     *
     * It can be set after the 'class instance' is created.
     *
     * @param array currentPath to this value
     * @param string nodeType - leaf or children
     *
     * @return mixed if not empty will be added to the paths
     */
    protected function callNodeProcessor(array $currentPath,
                                             $isTopALeaf)
    {

        if ($this->callLeafNodesOnly) {
            if ($isTopALeaf)  {
                return call_user_func($this->nodeProcessor,
                                       $currentPath,
                                       $isTopALeaf);
            }
        }
        else {
            return call_user_func($this->nodeProcessor,
                                   $currentPath,
                                   $isTopALeaf);
        }
    }

    /**
     * If you don't provide a callable to generate paths then this will be used.
     *
     * It generates a string of names separated by '/'. i.e. it looks like a filepath.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function defaultNodeProcessor()
    {
        $dnp = function(array $currentPath,
                         $isTopALeaf)  {

                $fullPath = '/';
                foreach($currentPath as $key => $node) {
                    $fullPath .= $node['name'] .'/';
                }
                return rtrim($fullPath, '/');
             };
         return $dnp;
    }
}
```

#### Source Data Format:

```
/*
 * Tree Node:
 *
 * Array(
 *        "name" => 'Furniture',
 *        "slug" => 'furniture',
 *        "children" => Array( // can be other Tree nodes...
 *                          ),
 *      );
 *
 *  The `children` key is optional, if empty or missing, means it is a `leaf` node
 *
 *  !!! Note: The only array entry checked in here is 'children' !!!
 *
 *  But you would need to overide the default nodeProcessor.
 */
```

#### Sample Test Data

```
$srcTree = Array(
  0 => Array(
          "name" => 'Furniture',
          "Slug" => 'furniture',
          "children" => Array(
                  "0" => Array
                      (
                          "name" => 'Sofa',
                          "Slug" => 'sofa',
                          "children" => Array
                              (
                                 "0" => Array ( "name" => '3 Seater', "Slug" => '3-seater'),
                                 "1" => Array ( "name" => '4 Seater', "Slug" => '4-seater'),
                              ),

                      ),

                  "1" => Array
                      (
                          "name" => 'Chairs',
                          "Slug" => 'chairs',
                          "children" => Array
                              (
                                 "0" => Array ( "name" => '3 Seater', "Slug" => '3-seater'),
                                 "1" => Array ( "name" => '4 Seater', "Slug" => '4-seater'),
                              )

                      )

              )

      ),
      More entries here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullname = array();
$mainarrs = array(); //this is the array that will have your all the array data
$i=0;
foreach ( $mainarrs as $mainarr )
{

$temp = $mainarr['name'];

    foreach($mainarr as $anmain)
    {
        $temp2 = $anmain['name'];

        foreach($anmain as $lastmain)
        {
            $fullname[$i] = $temp."/".$temp2."/".$lastmain['name']
        }
    }
}

//now for the output that you expect to see is in $fullname array, you can loop through it to see the result.
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data set here : https://pastebin.com/CGPniY8C
I came by with this solution :

```
/* Initialize dataset */
$srcTree = Array(...dataset_pastebin...);

/* 
$children = List of children
$node_path = Original node path
$node_path_storage = Array to store all path found
*/
function getPathFromTree($children, $node_path, &$node_path_storage){
    $original_node_path = $node_path;
    foreach ($children as $child){
        $node_path = $original_node_path . '/' . $child['Slug'];
        array_push($node_path_storage, $node_path);
        if(!empty($child['children'])){
            getPathFromTree($child['children'], $node_path, $node_path_storage);
        }
    }
}

/* Usage */
$node_path_storage = array();
getPathFromTree($srcTree, '', $node_path_storage);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($node_path_storage, true) . '</pre>';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /furniture
    [1] => /furniture/sofa
    [2] => /furniture/sofa/3-seater
    [3] => /furniture/sofa/4-seater
    [4] => /furniture/chairs
    [5] => /furniture/chairs/3-seater
    [6] => /furniture/chairs/4-seater
    [7] => /furniture1
    [8] => /furniture1/sofa1
    [9] => /furniture1/sofa1/3-seater1
    [10] => /furniture1/sofa1/4-seater1
    [11] => /furniture1/chairs1
    [12] => /furniture1/chairs1/3-seater1
    [13] => /furniture1/chairs1/4-seater1
)
```